# C++ declaring multiple variables in the same line

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

I know that declaring variables like this `int a = 10, b = 15, c = 20` is possible and it's ok, but is it possible in any program in c++ programming language, to declare variables like this `int a, b, c = 10, 15, 20` where `a` need to be `10`, `b` need to be `15` and `c` to be `20`.

Is this possible and is it right way to declare variables like this in c++?

**EDIT**: Is it possible with the overloading operator `=`?

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: "is it right way" in my *opinion* multiple variables on the same line is never the right way.

Comment: i mean is it ok to do that. @Borgleader

Comment: Even if `int a, b, c = 10, 15, 20;` were legal, which it's not, I'm struggling to think of any way in which that syntax would be preferable or clearer than the perfectly legal `int a = 10, b = 15, c = 20;`.

Comment: @DanKorn it's ok. I now that `int a = 10, b = 15, c = 20;` is perfectly legal, but i just asked because it's interesting way. i see that in some languages is possible, but i don't know is it possible in c++. Thanks on answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler will issue an error for such declarations

```
int a, b, c = 10, 15, 20;
```

The only idea that comes to my head is the following :)

```
int a, b, c = ( a = 10, b = 15, 20 );
```

Or you could make these names data members of a structure

```
struct { int a, b, c; } s = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

> EDIT: Is it possible with the overloading operator =?

There is not used the copy asssignment operator. It is a declaration. The copy assignment operator is used with objects that are already defined.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
int a, b, c = 10, 15, 20;
```

is not valid, (and even if it is it would probably initialize `c` to `20` (with comma operator) and let `a` and `b` uninitialized.

using c-array/std::array/std::vector may be an option:

```
int carray[3] = {10, 15, 20};
std::array<int, 3> a = {10, 15, 20};
std::vector<int> v = {10, 15, 20};
```

now we have `carray[0] == a[0] && a[0] == v[0] && v[0] == 10`

Comment: What will be with 15 and 20? Will compiler report the error or not?

Comment: No, it's not valid. The grammar prevents you from using a comma operator   there.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know about arrays, but i asked about 3 different variables.